# Как можно кластеризовать пользователей по степени сходства их поведения?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, кластеризация

Имеется pandas DataFrame:

```
|'User1' |'User2'  |'Correlation'|
|--------|---------|-------------|
|'Ivanov'|'Petrov' |0.9|
|'Ivanov'|'Sidorov'|0.1|
|'Petrov'|'Sidorov'|0.2|
```

В итоге хотелось бы получить кластеры: 1: 'Ivanov', 'Petrov'; 2: 'Sidorov'
Пользователей много (несколько тысяч) и не между всеми посчитана корреляция. Есть подозрение, что в SciPy будет какой-то подходящий метод.

Comment: Вы уже знаете сколько кластеров вы хотите получить в результате? Или алгоритм сам должен принять такое решение в зависимости от данных?  Есть ли еще какие-либо числовые данные (фичи) кроме корреляции?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы сам алгоритм выбрал число кластеров. Из фичей только корреляция - в этом и проблема.

Comment: а как вы получили значение корреляции? может есть смысл делать кластеризацию на исходных данных?

Comment: Так было бы проще. Но как считалась корреляция - не знаю. Имею то, что имею...

Comment: т.е. у вас из входных данных только три столбца, указанных в вопросе??

Answer (score 0):

"Подходящий метод" - а точнее -  пару десятков "подходящих методов" не только "будут", но и "есть". Только не в Scipy. Они собраны в  библиотеке Scikit-learn. Ознакомиться с ними можно, например, по ссылке:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html

Читайте, выбирайте. Ну и книг/учебников по этой теме - навалом. На любой вкус, цвет, уровень вашей подготовки и навыков в программировании. Советую, все-таки, начать с них.

Comment: Спасибо! Но в случае, когда у меня только один вектор признаков, возможно ли применение методов из sklearn (k-means, bdscan и т.д.)? На сколько я понимаю, там нужно 2 и более векторов признаков.

Comment: Алгоритмы есть разные. Одни получают на вход вектор признаков, определенным образом считают расстояние между объектами и по этому расстоянию выполняют кластеризаци. Так что во-первых у вас есть возможность использовать только вторую часть указанной процедуры. Кроме того, есть алгоритмы, специально заточенные на случай когда "расстояние" уже задано. В вашем случае "расстоянием" можно считать (при некоторых ограничениях, которые надо, естественно проверить) корреляция между объектами. P.S. Если ответ вам чем-то пригодился -  не забудьте про правила форума.